# LinqtoSQL simple question on how to update a table value

Tags: c#, linq

To all,

I'm new to LinqtoSql using C# in VS2015.  The code (below) retrieves what I wish from the server table, performs the function SendSMS properly, however, I don't know how to update the DateTimeSent value in the underlying table.  I look at the smsunsentline variable and intellisense says it is a local variable so I know I'm not using the linked variable I need to do the update.  Any help welcome.

Greg

```
    protected void SendQueueButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string smsexception;
        SMSClassesDataContext dbContext = new SMSClassesDataContext();
        var unsent = from SMSsent in dbContext.SMSsents where SMSsent.DateTimeSent == null select SMSsent;
        foreach (SMSsent smsunsentline in unsent)
        {
            smsexception = "";
            SendSMS(smsunsentline.To, smsunsentline.Message, ref smsexception);
            smsunsentline.DateTimeSent = DateTime.Now;
            dbContext.SubmitChanges();
        }

    }
```

Comment: A while since I used LinqToSql but that looks OK to me? You're sure it doesn't work? You're right that smsunsentline is a local variable, but LinqToSql handles the connection between the variables and the underlying table data.

Comment: (Though as a side-issue, you should wrap access to SMSClassesDataContext in a `using` since it's an IDisposable.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your SMSSent class have one (or more) fields flagged as members of the table's primary key?

Even if the underlying table doesn't have a primary key, L2S needs to have a set of members that can be treated as a primary key for the purpose of identifying the record that is going to be updated. If no members are marked as members of the primary key, it will not be able to update records.

Comment: Outstanding!!  I missed this someone in my reading.  Works perfect now.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems okay, you should probably wrap in a using Statement

```
using(var context = new SMSClassesDataContext()) {
    var unsentsms = context.SMSsents.Where(x => x.DateTimeSent == null);

    foreach(var sms in unsentsms) {
       SendSMS(sms.To, sms.Message, out string smsexception);
       sms.DateTimeSent = DateTime.Now;
       context.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but still no change occurs in the underlying table. in the DateTimeSent field.